# Как найти все реализации интерфейса на этапе выполнения?

Tags: java, плагин, classloader

Код на java содержит интерфейс (допустим MyInterface). Он собирается в jar архив и далее используется как библиотека для реализаций.

Каждая реализация этого интерфейса также находится в своем отдельном jar архиве.

Есть основной код, который не знает, как называются реализации (возможно у них совпадающие имена), известен только интерфейс.

Можно ли как-то "просканировать" jar архивы, находящиеся в classpath (или в каталоге), чтобы использовать реализации, не зная о их названии? Главное, найти как-то их все на этапе выполнения. Получается что-то типа загрузки плагинов